# org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: localized_values

Tags: java, spring, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I am trying to using `spring test dbunit`.

https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/

As I am using spring `4.1.x` I decided to use version `1.2.1` for `spring-test-dbunit` and `2.5.2` for core `dbunit`.

Originally I used plain `dbunit` and it worked fine. Then I decided to try `spring-test-dbunit` and I got several problems.

Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = {
        "classpath:path/to/test/context/sql-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection = "databaseConnection")
@DatabaseSetup("classpath:path/to/dataset/questionRepositoryTestDS.xml")
public class QuestionRepositoryDbUnitTest {

    ....

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void mustReturnQuestion() throws Exception {
        ....
        assertEquals("Result is not the same as expected!", expected,
                repository.findQuestion(QUESTION_ID_1, PRODUCT_CONFIGURATION_ID_1, LANGUAGE));
    }
```

My dataset file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <question question_id='q_mail' display_type='EMAIL' display_group='2' organization_uid='123' display_order='1'/>
    <question question_id='q_copies' display_type='NUMBER' display_group='1' organization_uid='123' display_order='1'/>

    <localized_question question_id='q_mail' language='EN' organization_uid='*' display_label='What is your email?'/>
    <localized_question question_id='q_mail' language='EN' organization_uid='123' display_label='Enter the mailbox'/>
    <localized_question question_id='q_copies' language='EN' organization_uid='*' display_label='How many copies you are planning to create?'/>


    <localized_values question_select_value_id='a_mail1' language='EN' organization_uid='*' display_label='common@email.com'/>
    <localized_values question_select_value_id='a_mail1' language='EN' organization_uid='123' display_label='custom@email.com'/>
    <localized_values question_select_value_id='a_mail2' language='EN' organization_uid='*' display_label='null@email.com'/>
</dataset>
```

Database connection bean looks like this

```
<bean id="databaseConnection"
        class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="schema" value="mySchema"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="customDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

where `dataSource` bean is

```
    <bean id="customDataSource"
          class="com.custom.db.embedded.EmbeddedH2DatabaseFactory">
        <property name="resourcesFromPaths">
            <list value-type="java.lang.String">
                <value>#{systemProperties['test-changelog']}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:product.pricing;MVCC=TRUE"/>
        <property name="createCommonTablesOnStartup" value="false"/>
    </bean>
```

But when I try to run test I get this error

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: localized_values
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:305)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:194)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:66)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:186)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is the problem?

Also when I used plain `dbunit` I had to set `autoCommit` in order to make it work

```
  databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection(h2databaseResource.getConnection(), DATABASE_SCHEMA);
  databaseConnection.getConnection().setAutoCommit(true);
```

(though I thought that `autoCommit` supposed to be `true` by default)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a late answer but I think your issue is that you haven't created your schema correctly. I see that you are using a custom data source factory and I would recommend you switch over to using a more standardized DB initialization, like putting this in your test XML configuration:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-schema.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Or declaring a test `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class TestDbConfig {

    @Value("classpath:com/foo/sql/db-schema.sql")
    private Resource schemaScript;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
        final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
        return initializer;
    }

    private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript(schemaScript);
        return populator;
    }

}
```